# Pig CSVExcelStorage remove header

Tags: apache-pig

I've seen that there is a constructor which accepts header control parameter

```
CSVExcelStorage(String delimiter, String multilineTreatmentStr, String eolTreatmentStr, String headerTreatmentStr)
```

However I haven't found what is the value of "SKIP_INPUT_HEADER" constant.

Comment: Why you want constant value of "SKIP_INPUT_HEADER"?, you can directly pass this MACRO to constructor during load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why you want the constant value of SKIP_INPUT_HEADER but if your intention is to remove the header during load, then please check the below example

```
input.csv
Name,Age,Location
a,10,chennai
b,20,banglore

PigScript:(With SKIP_INPUT_HEADER)
REGISTER '/tmp/piggybank.jar';
A  = LOAD 'input.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'UNIX', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER');
DUMP A;

Output:
(a,10,chennai)
(b,20,banglore)



PigScript:(Without SKIP_INPUT_HEADER)
REGISTER '/tmp/piggybank.jar';
A  = LOAD 'input.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'UNIX');
DUMP A;

OutPut:
(Name,Age,Location)
(a,10,chennai)
(b,20,banglore)
```